# Creating circle that looks like an authorized seal with code

Tags: php, graphics

I want to draw an irregular circle entirely with php (or another programming option) but without photoshop. The circle I'm trying to draw should be slightly irregular and I think the line thickness should vary slightly to give the impression of an authorized seal. I don't mind suggestions for a graphics package, as long as it uses code (not image manipulation for artists). Any code has been written for this? How can I get to a similar effect?

Comment: Please show an example. Although I'm fairly sure this will be pretty hard to do with pure code. What do you want to achieve? Would building this on ready-made graphics (that then get scaled, manipulated...) not be an option?

Comment: Consider using a pre-rendered image (or a collection of pre-rendered images) for this, which you can then rotate/scale, and superimpose text upon. Most likely the results will far more visually pleasing than trying to do this programmatically.

Comment: @Pekka I wish I had an example, but will keep looking. Even if I don't find any, I think most of us are familiar with what I'm talking about. They're on many official documents, and the one I'm describing is the one entirely made of ink.

Comment: a stamp-like ragged seal is extremely difficult to build using pure code. Why go through all the trouble? What for? Why not use a (Bitmap or vector) template?

Comment: Do one of these look at all like what you are trying to achieve? http://www.google.com/images?q=official+seal&oi=image_result_group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend [raphael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Right on their home page they show you how to draw a circle, but you can draw paths as well with vector lines, which would allow you to create an irregular circle.  Plus,it works on IE6+, as well as Firefox, Safari, Chrome.

Try using cos(x) for the x value and sin(y) for the y value in JavaScript with short paths and a random number for irregularity.

Comment: I'm not looking for any kind of circle. Can you tell me how to draw a circle similar to what I described. I already can draw a circle with GD library in PHP.

Comment: What I meant was to draw short paths using cos for the x value and sin for the y value.  You can set the 'stroke-width' for each 1-pixel path, making it appear irregular.  Use random numbers for the irregularity? NOTE: you would have to use JavaScript to do this, as Raphael is a JavaScript library

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to texture a circle, a simple [Bump map/Displacement map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_map) may do the trick. You'll still need to use some source image for the map.

The next trick is to find a package that supports a displacement map. SVG has a [displacement map filter](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feDisplacementMapElement), but I'm sure there're php libs with a nice set of filters if you're concerned about SVG's browser support.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use SVG.  Graphics can be describe as text and rendered at runtime.

Comment: That's a good idea, but a format recommendation alone won't help him to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: SVG is an ok option for me. Can you point me to a code sample for the effect I described in my question?

Comment: you can do a google image search on 'svg seal' and see lots of examples.